# Cannot parse to Nokogiri in rake task

Tags: ruby, rake, nokogiri

I am new to Nokogiri, I am trying to scrape search result of Baidu. I write a simple script to test. It reads the first page of search keyword `stackoverflow` and output the length of the document and the count of the result links on the first page(should be 10), it runs quite correctly.

```
# coding: utf-8
require 'rubygems'
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'

url = 'http://www.baidu.com/s?wd=stackoverflow&pn=0'
parsed_uri = URI.parse(URI.escape(url))
read_uri = parsed_uri.read
puts "URI read length: #{read_uri.to_s.length}"
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(read_uri)
puts "Nokogiri document length: #{doc.to_s.length}"
puts "result link count: #{doc.css('h3.t a').count}"
```

The result output:

```
$ ruby scrap_baidu.rb
URI read length: 37659
Nokogiri document length: 38226
result link count: 10
```

But when I move it to a rake task of a new rails 3 app:

```
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'

namespace :batch do
  desc "test"
  task :test_fetch => :environment do
    url = 'http://www.baidu.com/s?wd=stackoverflow&pn=0'
    parsed_uri = URI.parse(URI.escape(url))
    read_uri = parsed_uri.read
    puts "URI read length: #{read_uri.to_s.length}"
    doc = Nokogiri::HTML(read_uri)
    puts "Nokogiri document length: #{doc.to_s.length}"
    puts "result link count: #{doc.css('h3.t a').count}"
  end
end
```

I got totally different result:

```
$ bundle exec rake batch:test_fetch
URI read length: 37964
Nokogiri document length: 11824
result link count: 0
```

The document length is totally not correctly. It looks like `Nokogiri` is acting differently. I am not so sure `.length` is a method to see the insight of this, but this is what I could only think of when I find the difference.

Why is that?

Answer (score 0):

Nokogiri can do fixups to the HTML to make it parse sensibly to it, and also truncate blank text nodes, insert carriage returns, etc.

For instance:

```
irb(main):001:0> require 'nokogiri'
true
irb(main):002:0> html = '<html><head></head><body>foo</body></html>'
"<html><head></head><body>foo</body></html>"
irb(main):003:0> html.length
42
irb(main):004:0> Nokogiri::HTML(html).to_s.length
220
irb(main):005:0> Nokogiri::HTML(html).to_s
"<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd\">\n<html>\n<head><meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html; charset=UTF-8\"></head>\n<body>foo</body>\n</html>\n"
irb(main):006:0> html = '<html>     <head></head>     <body>foo</body></html>'
"<html>     <head></head>     <body>foo</body></html>"
irb(main):007:0> Nokogiri::HTML(html).to_s
"<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd\">\n<html>\n<head><meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html; charset=UTF-8\"></head>\n<body>foo</body>\n</html>\n"
```

You can control its parsing behavior by adding/adjusting [the parsing options](http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/ParseOptions.html). By default it uses `DEFAULT_HTML`.

Comment: Thanks @theTinMan, I didn't get you. How this explains the differences between running in a single ruby script and running in rails rake task?

Comment: It's an answer why you can't count on getting the same number of characters comparing the source and parsed data.

Comment: ok, yes, you are correct. But I found this problem is quite strange. I could not think of other ways to crack it now. So I compare the number of characters. Although it's not accurate, I still believe that 11824 to 38226, such a big difference, mean there's something wrong with the parsing.